# How to select first td element and its text with Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html-table, jquery-selectors

I want to change the "Yes! Pick me" into "Picked" with Jquery in the following HTML structure, I used `$('#myDiv>table>tr>td>table>tr').eq(1).text("Picked");` But it was not working. Could someone shed some light on this please? Thanks!

FYI, the first td of the the first table itself contains another table...

```
 <div id="myDiv">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <table>
            <tr>
              <td>Yes! Pick me!</td>

              <td>Not me..</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td>Not me..</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>

        <td>Not me..</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>Not me..</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
```

---

The section `$('#myDiv>table>tr>td>table>tr>td').eq(1).text("Picked");` does the trick, I forgot the last td part. Thanks to Rocket and everyone's help.

Comment: why don't you give ids for the fields you want to select?

Comment: Hi Neysor, b/c that part of the code is auto generated by an ASP.net user control. I'm just posting a sample code here to show similar structure for easier reference. thx

Comment: Hi, Rocket, worked like a charm! Thanks a Ton!!! Sloppy me~

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("#myDiv table table td:first").text("Picked")
```

Comment: I suggest `$('table table td:first', '#myDiv')` to make sure you don't select another table. :-)

Comment: thanks, bfavaretto, so I guess with the spaces, this way it only select the "first appearance of that tag" then?

Comment: @eastboundr The spaces mean "descendant". So "table table" means a table inside another table (with anything, like `<tr>` and `<td>` in the middle). `td:first` means the first `<td>`(inside of a table, inside of another table, which is inside of a div with `id == myDiv`).

Answer (score 4):

```
$('#myDiv').find('table table td').eq(0).text(...);
```

Start your selection at the `#myDiv` element (`$('#myDiv')`), then find all the TD element that are inside a table that is inside another table (`.find('table table td')`), then only alter the first one (`.eq(0)`).

Documentation:

- `.find()`: http://api.jquery.com/find
- `.eq()`: http://api.jquery.com/eq

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that you want `.eq(0)` not `.eq(1)` as `.eq()` is 0-based, and you are not selecting the `td`, only the `tr`.

Other than that using `>` direct descendant selectors makes your selection not very robust at all.

Try `$('#myDiv table table td').eq(0).text('Picked');`

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
$("td:contains('Yes! Pick me!')").text("Picked"); ​
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the :contains(text) selector

```
$('#myDiv td table td:contains(Yes! Pick me!)').text('Picked');
```

Be careful with nested tables however because if you were to use just

```
$('#myDiv td:contains(Yes! Pick me!)').text('Picked');
```

You would get both the cell your after plus the cell it is nested within.

Answer (score 0):

Your child selector query won't work because HTML5 requires the parser to insert `<tbody>` elements inside your `<table>` elements, since you've forgotten to put them in yourself. Perhaps you should consider validating your HTML?