# How to select this specific td element with its text with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I want to change the "Yes! Pick me" into "Picked" with Jquery in the following HTML structure. How should I select it? Please shed some light, thanks!

I tried $('#myDiv>table>tr').eq(1) but don't know how to continue...

```
 <div id="myDiv">
        <table>

          <tr>
            <td>Not me..</td>

            <td>Not me..</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>Not me..</td>

            <td>Yes! Pick me~ </td>
          </tr>

    </table>

    </div>
```

Comment: Isn't this the same as your other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9437914/how-to-select-this-specific-td-element-and-its-text-with-jquery ?

Comment: hi j08691, it's not really the same. this time i need to select something that is not always the first appearance of the same tags. e.g. <tr> is second appearance of its kind. <td> is also 2nd appearance of its kind... Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `:contains` selector.

```
$('#myDiv').find('td:contains(Yes! Pick me~ )').text('Picked');
```

If you can't query for the contained text, do it like

```
$('#myDiv tr:eq1(1) td:last').text('Picked');
```

Comment: wow thx jAndy, $('#myDiv tr:eq1(1) td:last').text('Picked');
 worked like a charm. except for some reason in my actual code, i want to select the third appearance of the <tr>, but I have to use tr:eq(3) instead of tr:eq(4). strange...maybe <tbody> count as one <tr> ?  anyways, it solves the problem for now, thanks

Comment: @eastboundr: well, you need to find a very unique property how you can identify the `td` you want to modify. based on that you can choose a selector

Comment: nvm, i found that i mis-read a hidden tr that exists inside another td. so the code worked just fine. Thanks again.

Comment: Hi jAndy, maybe I want to ask a follow up question. for the tr:eq(1) part. Could I replace the 1 with a variable in javascript? For example, tr:eq(loopNum) where loopNum is a variable. Thanks!!

Comment: @eastboundr: yes, of course you can. You either would build that string with `+` operators or use `.replace()`. Eg `'tr:eq(' + loopNum + ')'`

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
$('td:contains("Yes! Pick me~ ")');
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/WWYSf/1/).

Or:

```
$('tr:eq(1) td:eq(1)');
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/WWYSf/2/).

References:

- [`:contains` selector](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/).
- [`:eq()` selector](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/).

Comment: thanks, the second one works. as I could not predict the dynamically generated text.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple, just add a class to your td that you want to change like this:

```
<td class="to-change">Yes! Pick me~</td>
```

And jquery

```
$("td.to-change").html("Picked!");
```

Comment: sorry i cannot really change the code. It's more like a post-modification of some pre-generated code. thanks anyways.