# How to select a td from a table with id using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table with td's with id. I need to select those td's and reorder the columns.

```
$('table tr').each(function () {
    var tr = $(this);
    var tds = $('#Status');
    var tdA = $('#Address');
    alert(tds.innerHtml); //Here am getting a blank msg
    tds.remove().insertAfter(tda); //This is what i need to do 
});
```

Comment: start with http://learn.jquery.com/ then http://api.jquery.com/ and http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: then you will find the answer as `$('#tableid td')`

Comment: some specific selections could also be done [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9437914/how-to-select-this-specific-td-element-and-its-text-with-jquery]

Comment: $('#header tr').each(function() {
                var tr = $(this);
                var td1 = tr.find('td #id');}); This is not working

Comment: $('table tr').each(function() {
                var tr = $(this);
                tds = tr.find('td');
               
                for (var n = 0; n < trs.length; n++) {
                    alert(tds[n].id.toString());
                }
               
          

            });

Comment: The above as well as dosent work

Comment: What more should i give , am not familiar with asking questions

Comment: It appears as if you may have multiple elements with the same ID looking at the selection you are doing within the loop. It is being discussed in the comments below that it is an incorrect practice as specified by W3C and I would imagine that your initial selectors were retrieving the same element each time.  Additionally `$('#selector')` returns a jQuery object and not a dom element as expected by innerhtml.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found the answer:

`var tds = tr.find("td[id='Status']");` **//what i was looking for**

Thanks for ur support and special thanks for voting my genuine question 2 points down :D, since iam not point hungry, No offense :-)

Comment: If there are not duplicating sets of ids, then you may not need the tr.find(). For my situation, turns out I just needed $("td[id='Status']") odd that the $("td#Status") format did not seem to work for me (which is what brought me here)...

Answer (score 3):

```
var selectedTd = $("#ID_OF_TD");
```

or to call the method like on click etc etc you can directly call the method

```
$("#ID_OF_TD").click(function(){

});
```

you need to put this code in document ready section ..

```
$("document").ready(function(){             
        $("#ID_OF_TD").click(function(){
            alert('td clicked');
        });     
});
```

Comment: hey but this will return the particular td, if its working for you thats great.. but as now I can see you have changes the question and now you are saying you want to reorder the column, is it so? then lot of other code you have to do.. I hope you will not able to do this. else let me know..

Answer (score 0):

Simply do `$("#idHere")`.

More Info: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: As i sad before, id's easy could be duplicated, but ofcourse, it's better to use class names, neither id's.

Comment: @FSou1 Then what is the point of calling it an "ID"? A class could be used instead!

Comment: Your best proof - term 'ID'? That's sick, because my proof - working code in demo, so you can discuss about terms, while my code still works.

Comment: @FSou1 There is a difference in the working code and perfect code.

Comment: Perfect code does not mean that i can't use it or ID's cannot be duplicated as you commented. The main idea that it could be, but it's not perfect.

Comment: @FSou1 Just think if some other person has an ID same as yours, both of them work, but would you be happy?

Comment: Rahul, your replay was not correct. I could accept that if you wrote 'This is not good practise', but you replied 'ID could not be duplicated' and this comment i can't accept

Comment: Is that the reason you downvoted my answer? Seriously?

Comment: You should go read Stackoverflow rules before you do anything stupid like this, again.

Comment: @FSou1 ID cannot be duplicated. **It is specified in every single HTML specification.** There's a reason that `document.getElementById('id')` will only return one element. There's a reason that `$('#id')` returns only one element.

Comment: @FSou1 if you want an official link, please look up the HTML5 living standard body. The developer version offers an easy-to-read one: http://developers.whatwg.org/content-models.html#the-id-attribute Note that it says: `The value must be unique amongst all the IDs in the element's home subtree and must contain at least one character. The value must not contain any space characters.`

Comment: Florian Margaine, Yeah, that's great about returning only one element, until you shouldn't use specifing condition in selector like `$('td#a')`...  http://jsfiddle.net/suc8p/

Comment: I can accept word 'should', but not 'must' in sentence: `You *word* use unique ID's`

Comment: @FSou1 You're making a foul of yourself, please read attentively Florian's comment and stop argue against the whole world, HTML specifications included

Comment: I understand that you have just one argue why ID must be unique- specification. Excellent score on exam.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Id Selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)

```
$('#tdID')
//^# followed by html id
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery apply: `$('#td_ID')`

Answer (score 0):

we can use :

```
$('table > tr > td#Status');
$('table > tr > td#Address');
```